# LINQ Expression tree with Substring

Tags: c#, .net, expression, binary-search-tree, expression-trees

I want to create SQL LINQ expression like:

```
.Where(product => product.name.Substring(3,5).Contains("ma")
```

Can someone help me to create that expression?

```
Expression.PropertyOrField(body, "name.Substring(3,5)");
```

I tried, but I am getting an error

> Substring(3,5) is not a member of type 'System.String'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we have a class `Product`:

```
public class Product
{
    public string name;
}
```

Then you can create your `Expression` as:

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> expression = product => product.name.Substring(3, 5).Contains("ma");
Console.WriteLine(expression); // product => product.name.Substring(3, 5).Contains("ma")
```

If you need to create your expression manually consider this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "product");
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "name"),
            typeof(string).GetMethod("Substring", new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }),
            Expression.Constant(3, typeof(int)),
            Expression.Constant(5, typeof(int))),
        typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }),
        Expression.Constant("ma", typeof(string))),
    parameter);
Console.WriteLine(expression); // product => product.name.Substring(3, 5).Contains("ma")
```

Hope was helpful for you.